# compare a part of the string in string arrays

Tags: vb.net

I have two string array lists and I want to compare a portion of the string. I can use except method to find the differences but how to take a portion of the the string and compare?
For instance

```
File1:
PartA_Rev1
File2:
PartA_Rev2
```

I want to compare only the first portion of the string (PartA)
Thanks

Comment: in your comparer you expand it to split on "_" and just compare `parts(1)` when it has that prefix

Comment: Actually, they will compare the same with and without "PartA_" in the string since it is the same in both cases.  Based on a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36962023/1070452) I am guessing that you want the part with numerals to compare like numbers...but I am guessing and that isnt the question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstood you, but wouldnt substring work?

```
str1.substring(0,5).equals(str2.substring(0,5))
```